# Who are the five figures in the niches in the 'Monument of Marchese Spinetta Malaspina'

Tags: identification, renaissance, monument

I couldn't find online who are the five figures in the niches in the 'Monument of Marchese Spinetta Malaspina'? Does anyone has any idea about their identity?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The five small statues in the niches of the cenotaph represent (from left to right) St. Jerome, St. John the Baptist and the Virgin and Child, a bearded male saint (perhaps St. Paul or St. Peter) and a figure who could be either the penitent Magdalene or St. Mary of Egpyt. Wolters noted their inclusion in Penuti’s engraving but disputed their original placement on the monument and that they dated to the first half of the 1400s, though he did not offer any alternatives. (Wolters, p.138, note 28) *[V&A](https://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O102495/monument-to-marchese-spinetta-malaspina-monument-firenze-antonio-da/)*

The V&A source provides a wealth of additional information about the monument. V&A references [Wolters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006ZCGSZS) for the specific information you seek.